# IF statement inside PHP function not working?

Tags: php, function, variables, if-statement, isset

This is very basic, I know - but I simply can't figure out why this short section of PHP code isn't working for me? I'm trying to get a IF statement happening in my function, and then execute the function somewhere on my document so it returns "../".

```
<?php $confirm = "yes"; ?>  

<?php
   function clientarea() {
      if (isset($confirm)) {
         if ($confirm == "yes") {
             echo "../";
         }
      }
   }
?>

<img src="<?php clientarea(); ?>images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
```

Any ideas why this code doesn't work for me?

Comment: For one thing, you're missing a closing `)` on your first `if` statement.

Comment: You are trying to accessing a global variable, that's the problem.

Comment: What you mean missing a "global" variable??

Comment: @AdamMcArthur See rationalboss's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work better:

```
<?php $confirm = "yes"; ?>  

<?php
   function clientarea($confirm) {
      if (isset($confirm)) {
         if ($confirm == "yes") {
             echo "../";
         }
      }
   }
?>

<img src="<?php clientarea($confirm); ?>images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
```

You can better use booleans instead of "yes" or "no"...

I modified your code:

```
<?php $confirm = true; ?>  

<?php
   function clientarea($confirm) {
      if ($confirm) {
             echo "../";
      }
   }
?>

<img src="<?php clientarea($confirm); ?>images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! - just quickly testing to see if it works :)

Comment: If confirm is a constant, consider using `define ('CONFIRM', true);`. Then you can check `if (CONFIRM) { echo "../"; }` without passing it as a parameter. If it can be changed at runtime, kindly disregard this comment. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php $confirm = "yes"; ?>  

<?php
   function clientarea() {
      global $confirm; // $confirm is not accessible from here so either you declare this as global or follow one of the answers in putting $confirm as a parameter of this function
      if (isset($confirm)) {
         if ($confirm == "yes") {
             echo "../";
         }
      }
   }
?>

<img src="<?php clientarea(); ?>images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (isset($confirm) {
```

should be

```
if (isset($confirm)) {
```

You're missing the closing paren.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - that was an error in my code, my bad!

Answer (score 2):

You forget a brace in your if-statement. You're code is:

```
if (isset($confirm) {
```

It should be:

```
if (isset($confirm)) {
```

Take a break. :)

Answer (score 1):

you lack close parenthesis in the `IF` condition

```
(isset($confirm) should be (isset($confirm))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use global inside your function

```
<?php $confirm = "yes"; ?>  

<?php
   function clientarea() {
      global $confirm; 
      if (isset($confirm)) {
         if ($confirm == "yes") {
             echo "../";
         }
      }
   }
?>

<img src="<?php clientarea(); ?>images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   function clientarea() {
      if (isset($confirm)) {
         if ($confirm == "yes") {
             echo "../";
         }
      }
   }
```

missing a closing ) after `isset($confirm)`